# How to show number of new messages in a balloon in navbar?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, icons, navbar

My website's navbar is below. I want to add something like a balloon beside the *Messaging* option and have it indicate the number of new messages... something like what we see on Facebook, or even here on Stack Overflow.

I can get number of new messages from the database but the problem is how to show it like I said above.

I'm using Bootstrap.

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div style="min-width:1280px;" class="navbar-inner">
        <ul class="nav pull-right">
            <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
            <li><a href="MasFeedback.aspx">feedback</a></li>
            <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
            <li><a href="MasProjects.aspx">Projects</a></li>
            <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
            <li><a href="MasWeekSchedule.aspx">Schedule</a></li>
            <li class="divider-vertical input-append"></li>
            <li><a href="MasMessaging.aspx">MESSAGING</a></li>
            <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
            <li><a href="MasProfile.aspx">Profile</a></li>
            <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
            <li><a href="MasHome.aspx">Home</a></li>
            <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
        </ul>
        <asp:LinkButton CssClass="brand" ID="LinkButton5" runat="server" Font-Size="Large" Font-Underline="False" Style="color: #FF0000; font-weight: 700; padding-left:120px;" OnClick="LinkButton4_Click" ForeColor="Red" Text="خروج از سامانه"></asp:LinkButton>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What triggers the display of the number of messages? Click of the link button? Hover over the link button?

Comment: its in master page and triggers with every page load!

Comment: see: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#badges

Comment: Thank you very much Bass Jobsen. this is exactly what I need! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see: getbootstrap.com/components/#badges – From Bass Jobsen